# When was a ParseObject pinned?

Tags: android, parse-platform

If I pin a parseobject to the local data store, is there a way to find the last pin's pinned at timestamp? Or is there a way to find when the object set with the tag supplied to the pin last updated at?

Edit 1: I am trying to pass the query result to a RecyclerView. After fetching it initially, I am pinning the last retrieved object list to the local data store. I don't want my recycler view to query again within a time difference of five minutes. So I want to check, the timestamp of the last pinned object set before I will query again if needed.

Comment: Not sure if it is directly available, but it is not difficult to add your own timestamp which you can use. I assume that you refer to newly created objects so that no createdAt or updatedAt is yet added?

Comment: @cYrixmorten Thanks for the comment. I have updated my question with my use case.

Comment: With that use case I would simply store a timestamp in shared preferences. Would be simple and works even on app restarts.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Thank you, That should work! Being a noob, i missed it completely.

Comment: Oh an by the way.. Do you use ParseQueryAdapter together with the RecycleView? Cause then I would love to see how they are properly tailored together, if you have a reference or a code snippet.

Comment: I am using a custom adapter class, as ParseQueryAdapter is not extending RecyclerView.Adapter. Hence, I am running into a lot of issues when trying to get the RecyclerView to work. I am not able to solve this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338314/recyclerview-onbindviewholder-onclicklistener-behavior  . Kindly look into the other question and see if you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly the kind of problems I could imagine running into, which made me hesitate making the jump to RecycleView. I'll have a look at the link now.